# Unable to add more than one directory in gulp.dest

Tags: gulp, gulp-jscs

I am trying to run jscs using the following code.

```
var _files = ["main.js", "src/*.js"];

gulp
.src(_files)
.pipe(jscs(
{
configPath: __dirname+'/../.jscsrc',
esnext: true,
fix: true
}
))
.pipe(gulp.dest(''));
```

What should I pass in gulp.dest as I have files in two different directories?

"jscs -x dirName" individual works, but I am creating a generic gulp task which will run JSCS on all the folders and automatically fix the issues. And gulp.dest() only accepts one directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a forEach loop on the _files.
Credit: [gulp task to process files that are writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841664/gulp-task-to-process-files-that-are-writable)

```
var _files = ["main.js", "src/*.js"];

gulp.task('jscs-fix', function() {
    return _files.forEach(function(fn) {
        gulp.src(fn, {
                base: './'
            })
            .pipe(jscs({
                configPath: __dirname + '/../.jscsrc',
                esnext: true,
                fix: true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    });
});
```