# gulp task to process files that are writable

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio, gulp

I'm using Gulp in a VS2015 project to run [jscs](http://jscs.info/) on JavaScript files with the `fix` option set.  The intention is to modify the same file that is read (viz., source and destination are the same).

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jscs = require('gulp-jscs');
var chmod = require('gulp-chmod');
var exec = require('gulp-exec');

var ourJsFiles = // an array of files and globbed paths 

gulp.task('jscs', function (callback) {
   ourJsFiles.forEach(function (fn) {
      gulp.src(fn, { base: './' })
         .pipe(jscs({
            "preset": "google",
            "maximumLineLength": 160,
            "validateIndentation": 3,
            "fix": true
         }))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
   });
   callback();
});
```

But I do *not* want to process any files that are read-only.  Is there already a way to detect this in Gulp on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin which allows you to work with subset of files: [gulp-filter](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter).
One of options is to pass filter function which will receive [vinyl file object](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#file), so for e.g. you could use `stat.mode` property of that object which holds permissions and do something like:

```
var filter = require('gulp-filter');
...
var writableFiles = filter(function (file) {
        //https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3045
        var numericPermission = '0'+(e.stat.mode & parseInt('777', 8)).toString(8);
        return numericPermission[1]==='6'
    });
...
gulp.src(....)
    .pipe(writableFiles)
```